# reCaptcha Enterprise in django forms without django-recaptcha

Tags: django, forms, recaptcha, enterprise

How can I implement new `reCaptcha Enterprise` within django on the form without using old `django-recaptcha`?

Answer (score 1):

Ive deleted ***`django-recaptcha = "==2.0.6"`*** that used v2 or v3 reCaptcha not Enterprise (. But I`ve used logic of integration reCaptcha from there).
For It:

- install ***`google-cloud-recaptcha-enterprise = "==1.4.1"`***, provided credentials via string that obtain from google-console as key.json and set It to env;
  got credentials

```
RECAPTCHA_CREDENTIALS_JSON = ast.literal_eval(
    os.getenv("RECAPTCHA_CREDENTIALS_JSON", "{}",)
    .replace("\r", "\\r")
    .replace("\n", "\\n")
)
```

**RECAPTCHA_CREDENTIALS_JSON** should be provided as string like:

```
RECAPTCHA_CREDENTIALS_JSON="{ "type": "service_account", "project_id":..., "private_key": "..." ...., }"
```

- got `sitekey` for Enterprise `RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY`;

  RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = os.getenv("RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY", "...")
- added to INSTALLED_APPS `"django.forms",`;
- added to settings `FORM_RENDERER = "django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting"`;

In Forms.py:

```
from google.cloud import recaptchaenterprise_v1

RECAPTCHA_ACTION = "login"

if settings.RECAPTCHA_CREDENTIALS_JSON and settings.RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY:
    client = recaptchaenterprise_v1.RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient.from_service_account_info(
        settings.RECAPTCHA_CREDENTIALS_JSON
    )
else:
    client = None
```

Method that check result for captcha-field:

```
def create_assessment(token):
    """Create an assessment to analyze the risk of a UI action.
    Args:
    projectID: GCloud Project ID
    recaptchaSiteKey: Site key obtained by registering a domain/app to use recaptcha services.
    token: The token obtained from the client on passing the recaptchaSiteKey.
    recaptchaAction: Action name corresponding to the token.
    Return:
    bool: True if successful.
    """
    project_id = "....."
    recaptcha_site_key = settings.RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY
    recaptcha_action = RECAPTCHA_ACTION

    # Set the properties of the event to be tracked.
    event = recaptchaenterprise_v1.Event(expected_action=recaptcha_action)
    event.site_key = recaptcha_site_key
    event.token = token

    assessment = recaptchaenterprise_v1.Assessment()
    assessment.event = event

    project_name = f"projects/{project_id}"

    # Build the assessment request.
    request = recaptchaenterprise_v1.CreateAssessmentRequest()
    request.assessment = assessment
    request.parent = project_name

    response = client.create_assessment(request)

    # Check if the token is valid.
    if not response.token_properties.valid:
        logger.info(
            "The CreateAssessment call failed because the token was "
            + "invalid for for the following reasons: "
            + str(response.token_properties.invalid_reason)
        )
        return None
    return True
```

The method above receive `token` that we should get from "widget". Widget code:

```
class ReCaptchaBase(forms.widgets.Widget):
    """
    Base widget to be used for Google ReCAPTCHA.
    public_key -- String value: can optionally be passed to not make use of the
        project wide Google Site Key.
    """
    recaptcha_response_name = "g-recaptcha-response"
    template_name = "oauth2_provider/widget_v2_checkbox.html"

    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        return data.get(self.recaptcha_response_name, None)

    def build_attrs(self, base_attrs, extra_attrs=None):
        attrs = super(ReCaptchaBase, self).build_attrs(base_attrs, extra_attrs)
        attrs["data-callback"] = base_attrs.get("data-callback", "onloadCallback")
        attrs["sitekey"] = base_attrs.get("sitekey", settings.RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY)
        attrs["theme"] = base_attrs.get("theme", "light")
        attrs["action"] = base_attrs.get("action", RECAPTCHA_ACTION)
        return attrs
```

- `value_from_datadict`: helps me to get `client` token;
- `build_attrs`: attributes that passed to the template;

Add the field to the our form, Ive been rewriting the PasswordResetForm. Ive added it like a CharFiled within our widget.

```
class ReCaptchaField(forms.CharField):

    widget = ReCaptchaBase()

    def validate(self, value):
        if not create_assessment(value):
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages["required"], code="required"
            )
        return value
```

Form:

```
class CustomPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):
    """Reset password form override"""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomPasswordResetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not settings.RECAPTCHA_CREDENTIALS_JSON or not settings.RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY:
            self.fields.pop("captcha")

    captcha = ReCaptchaField()
```

- `__init__`: delete captcha whenever credentials unprovided

Add `captcha block` to the form in main template `password_reset_form.html`:

```
{% block captcha %}
<div class="justify-center">
    <div class="w-full flex mt-3 justify-center">
        {{ form.captcha }}
    </div>
    <div class="w-full flex mt-3 justify-center">
        <p>{{ form.errors.captcha }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock captcha %}
```

template for widget `widget_v2_checkbox.html`:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Submit function to be called, after reCAPTCHA was successful.
    var onloadCallback = function () {
        grecaptcha.enterprise.render('id_captcha', {
            'sitekey': '{{ widget.attrs.sitekey }}',
            'action': '{{ widget.attrs.action }}',
            'theme': '{{ widget.attrs.theme }}',
        });
    };
</script>
<div class="captcha" id="id_captcha" 
{% for name, value in widget.attrs.items %} 
    {% if value is not False %} {{name}} 
    {% if value is not True %}="{{ value|stringformat:'s' }}"
    {% endif %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}>
</div>
```